# 0x80070020 error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

I am facing this problem every time I run the project. The diagnosis hub console keeps on popping this message up:

```
Failed to commit package 'C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp\Report.ABF0E3A6-3DC5-4A16-92B9-F66196D76AF2' (0x80070020). Please check that the collector has access to the destination location.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error lookup tool says: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Then how to fix that? If it is used by another process, how can I find what is using it?

Comment: See if disabling any antivirus on the machine helps with the problem.

Comment: How to disable an antivirus on a windows 7 then?

Comment: I uninstalled an antivirus, and it worked!!!! Thanks people!!!!